# Editing subfolder names

Tags: batch-file, copy, rename

I'm trying to create a batch file which I send a folder to using `right-click` => `sendto`, creating two new folders in the same directory as the folder i sent to the batch file. The two new folders will be copies of a the folder i sent to the batch file named based upon two user input variables, say A and B. I want the subfolders within those two folders to also have the A and B added to them. `Test (Existing Folder sent to batch file)` -> `TestA(New Folder) and TestB(new folder)`. Then `TestA(new folder)\M1234567.D(subfolder)` -> `TestA(new folder)\M1234567A.D(renamed subfolder)` and the same thing happening to `TestB(new Folder)` and its sub folders.

Example: `A` and `B` added to folder `test` to become `testA` and `testB`. I need the entire contents of the folder to be copied to the two other folders as well. I have this part working with `robocopy`. The part I'm struggling with is then appending all of the subfolders within the two new folders to have the same letter added as the parent folder has added.

So as an example having `\testA\M1234567.D` changed to `\testA\M1234567A.D` and `testB\M1234567` changed to `testB\M1234567B.D`.

The subfolders in the two newly copied folders will contain subfolders with .D at the end. So in an effort to make sure those are the only ones that get the inputs added i specifically added the .D at the end of the rename.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
@ECHO off
cd /d %1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set appendLetter=ABCDEFG

SET /p appendLetter1="Enter the first letter you wish to append to the end of the Data Files: "
SET /p appendLetter2="Enter the second letter you wish to append to the end of the Data Files: "
if NOT "%appendLetter1%"=="ABCDEFG" (

ROBOCOPY "%1" "%1%appendLetter1%" /mir
ROBOcopy "%1" "%1%appendLetter2%" /mir

cd /D D:\MassHunter\Data\%1%appendLetter1%

Rename "???????.D" "???????%appendLetter1%.D"
cd /D D:\MassHunter\Data\"%1%appendLetter2%"

Rename "???????.D" "???????%appendLetter2%.D"

)
```

Comment: Your question needs to be a little clearer that you're wanting to add the user input parameters to the right clicked directory name, but the user provided parameters + `.D` to all of its subdirectories.

Comment: Im creating two new folders in the same directory as a copy of a current folder named based upon two user input variables, say A and B. I want the subfolders within those two folders to also have the A and B added to them. 
Test (Existing Folder) -> TestA(New Folder) and TestB(new folder). Then TestA(new folder)\M1234567.D(subfolder) -> TestA(new folder)\M1234567A.D(renamed subfolder) and the same thing happening to TestB(new Folder) and its sub folders.

Is that more clear? I will edit the OP if you agree.

Comment: The subfolders in the two newly copied folders will contain subfolders with .D at the end. So in an effort to make sure those are the only ones that get the inputs added i specifically put those in.

Comment: Please put all relevant information into your question by [edit]ing it, so everything is in one place. Regard that comments may become cleaned up...